# Proving that all delta-nbhd are open sets by using the contrapositive of the definition of an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I want to prove that all $\delta -nbhd$ are open sets the following way:

Let$\space E$ a $\delta -nbhd$

Take a point $m$ that is not an interior point of $E$ and prove that $m \notin E$

Here's my attempt at the proof:

$m$ is not an interior point of $E$

Therefore for all $\delta$, the $\delta -nbhd$ of $m \nsubseteq E$

But I'm not able to infer from that that $m \notin E$

Thanks!

Comment: Edit: Can't you say that if $A$ is a neighbourhood of m, then $m\in A\land A\not \subseteq E\Rightarrow m\notin E$?

Comment: Just a tip: It's better to use a different symbol than $\delta$ for the nbh's around $m$ as you used $\delta$ for the fixed nbh. Also somewhere you have to integrate the center of the $\delta$-nbh.

Comment: One retains more control with a direct proof. Let $p$ be a point, and let $E$ be the set of all $x$ such that $d(p,x)\lt \delta$. (Here $d$ is distance.) Suppose $a\in E$. Then $d(p,a)=\delta_1\lt \delta$. Let $\epsilon=(\delta-\delta_1)/2$. Argue from Triangle Inequality that the the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$ is contained in $E$.